# Debugging site written mainly in JScript with AJAX code injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging, accordion

I have a legacy code to maintain and while trying to understand the logic behind the code, I have run into lots of annoying issues.

The application is written mainly in Java Script, with extensive usage of jQuery + different plugins, especially Accordion. It creates a wizard-like flow, where client code for the next step is downloaded in the background by injecting a result of a remote AJAX request. It also uses callbacks a lot and pretty complicated "by convention" programming style (lots of events handlers are created on the fly based on certain object names - e.g. current page name, current step name).

Adding to that, the code is very messy and there is no obvious inner structure - the functions are scattered in the code, file names do not reflect the business role of the code, lots of functions and code snippets are most likely not used at all etc.

**PROBLEM:** How to approach this code base, so that the inner flow of the code can be sort-of "reverse engineered" using a suite of smart debugging tools.

Ideally, I would like to be able to attach to the running application and step through the code, breaking on each new function call.

Also, it would be nice to be able to create a "diagram of calls" in the application (i.e. in order to run a particular page logic, this particular flow of function calls was executed in a particular order).

Not to mention to be able to run a coverage analysis, identifying potentially orphaned code fragments.

I would like to stress out once more, that it is impossible to understand the inner logic of the application just by looking at the code itself, unless you have LOTS of spare time and beer crates, which I unfortunately do not have :/ (shame...)

An IDE of some sort that would aid in extending that code would be also great, but I am currently looking into possibility to use Visual Studio 2010 to do the job, as the site itself is a mix of Classic ASP and ASP.NET (I'd say - 70% Java Script with jQuery, 30% ASP).

I have obviously tried FireBug, but I was unable to find a way to define a breakpoint or step into the code, which is "injected" into the client JS using AJAX calls (i.e. the application retrieves the code by invoking an URL and injects it to the client local code). Venkman debugger had similar issues.

Any hints would be welcome. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use ["dynaTrace Ajax"](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) to create a diagram of calls, but it is not debugger. If you have access to that application you can use keyword "debugger" to define a breakpoint explicitly in javascript files. Visual Studio theoretically shows all of evaluated and loaded javascript code in Solution Explorer when you've attached to IE.

Comment: +1 for letting know about the tool. In the end I have managed by refactoring tiny bits of the code with unit tests in place to make sure, that changes do not break anything. After lots of iterations of changes the code started to make sense to the point that allowed a final refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with Chrome's developer tools and profiling single activities to find functions to set breakpoints on. Functions can be expanded to get their call stack.

That may or may not be helpful as it's entirely possible to get code that's too -- uh, unique, shall we say -- to make much sense of.

Good luck?